# LaTeX closing $ signs makes cursor jump

Tags: latex

I'm in LaTeX/PS mode and whenever I close my $ math statements the cursor jumps to the first $ and back to the closing $. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you are using  AUCTeX. According to the documentation of `TeX-insert-dollar` among other things the following happens if you input the closing $ sign:

> Show matching dollar sign if this dollar sign ends
>   the TeX math mode and ‘blink-matching-paren’ is non-nil.

What you can do is to set `blink-matching-paren` to `nil`.

**EDIT:** This will also affect the behaviour of emacs when you input a closing parenthesis etc., but you can use other modes e.g. `show-paren-mode` to still highlight the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, I'm using AUCTeX. What is supposed to happen for closing parenthesis? I don't think I see anything happen.

Comment: For parentesis I see the same behaviour that you describe for $, i.e. from ) the cursor jumps to ( if  `blink-matching-paren` is set to `t`. But if you don't like this behaviour anyway then this should be fine.

Comment: I see the first parenthesis gets highlighted when closing, but it doesn't make my cursor jump back and fourth like with $. Is it because I am using emacs evil mode? `blink-matching-paren` is set to `t`

Comment: You are right! There is no jumping of the cursor but only highlighting. Maybe you have (as do I) the `show-paren-mode` activated. Without that and `blink-matching-paren` set to `nil` there is no highlighting on my system.